# createLink not working as for file inside a read-only folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-teams

We are using Microsoft Graph's `/createLink` API to share items. We are facing strange issues with the follow scenarios:

1. A File shared as read-only to an account which appears in `/sharedWithMe` results. We are able to call `/createLink` for this file.
2. A Folder shared as read-only to an account which appears in `/sharedWithMe` results. We are *not* able to call `/createLink` for any files inside that folder.

Error Received:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "unauthenticated",
        "message": "The caller is not authenticated.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
            "date": "2017-11-07T12:54:50"
        }
    }
}
```

Our App is registered with `Files.ReadWrite.All`.

Why this difference in placing of files?

Comment: Are you saying this works as long as the folder wasn't shared as read-only?

Comment: Yes this was working if the folder is in write mode.FYR,This folder was created new and shared with read only permission.Same for the file too.